# How do I cause variables to expand within a smbclient command?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, smb

I am running the following commands:

```
FILES=`/usr/bin/find /u01/app/dw/admin/dgwspool -type f -daystart -mmin -1621`;
/usr/bin/smbclient //techshare.something.com/Depts/ -I 129.0.0.1 -D ITIS/deptshare/degreeworks/Test -U domain\\user%password -c "prompt off; mput $FILES"
```

I've tested this, the $FILES variable is filled with a space-delimited list of filenames. The smblclient command connects to the windows share as I would hope, and if I put in a hard-coded filename it will copy the file (or files) to the share.

What seems to be happening is that the $FILES variable is not expanded, or is being evaluated in some internal smbclient scope.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My psychic powers tells me that you tested this with `echo $FILES`, which printed all the files on one line, leading you to believe that `$FILES` was spaces separated. This is not the case.

With `echo $FILES`, the shell word splits the variable on spaces and line feeds into multiple arguments, which `echo` then joins with spaces. If you use `echo "$FILES"`, you'll see that it is in fact line feed separated.

The quick fix is to print the file names space separated (requires GNU find or other find with `-printf`). As per comment, it also omits the search path:

```
FILES=`/usr/bin/find /u01/app/dw/admin/dgwspool -type f -daystart -mmin -1621 -printf '%P '`;
```

Comment: You are right that they're line-feed separated. But even with this fix, it still acts as if it's not expanding in the smbclient statement.

Comment: Is this the literal code you're using, or is it part of a larger script? If you add the line `set -x` before the smbclient line, does it show the filenames expanded?

Comment: This is the literal code. It will be added to the end of a shell script that does something else, but is independent of that code. I've only munged the server addresses and passwords, everything else is as I'm using it. I'm testing on the command line, as a semicolon-separated single line. Ah crap, it looks like it is expanding, but smbclient isn't doing anything with the list.

Comment: It didn't like the path prefixed to each item in the list. I'm accepting your answer and adding an improvement that will overcome that problem.